# How can I represent with UML a process that involves queues?

Tags: multithreading, uml, modeling, process, queue

I would like to use UML diagrams to show some processes I am designing and would like to implement.

The processes involve using a queue, and adding and taking out elements from it.

- In *one* of this process the adding and taking out elements are done by two different threads.
- In the other, both operations are done by the same thread.

So far I have used sequence diagrams to represent the process involving multithreads, but these diagrams don't have the level of granularity to show the queues processing,

Which is the best way to represent this with UML?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: So far I have used sequence diagrams to represent the process involving multithreads, but these diagrams don't have the level of granularity to show the queues processing, that is why I asked

Comment: @KansaiRobot: don't bury any additional information in a comment section., Instead, use the "edit" button to improve your question. And did you notice: you can post images like sequence diagrams there as well.

Comment: @KansaiRobot I’ve edited the question to include your important comment. Questions on SE should be self-contained because many people here read just the question, decide whether it’s ok or not, and vote. Comments are often read only when there is an interest in the subject.

Comment: Within a big project, we came to the solution NOT using UML for this but using BPMN with lanes etc... Just as an idea, if this helps.

Comment: @WalterKuhn I would be interested in any objective references that you have to support this claim.  I'm asking because I think I've read some research work from HPI that demonstrated equivalence between BPMN and UML activity diagrams in the area of business process management (where BPMN is more used) with a comparable readbility for non-experts. If queuing semantic is sufficiently defined in BPMN to address this question, don't hesitate to propose an alternate answer to share with the community

Answer (score 3):

Your modelling requirement strongly suggest to use [UML *activity diagram*](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html) which:

- allows to represent processes
- can represent concurrency through [fork](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#fork-node) and [join](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#join-node) nodes
- can show [object flows](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-objects.html) within the processes
- provide for a [central buffer](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-objects.html#central-buffer) for queuing data in addition to the queuing possibility of every activity involved in object flow
- even provide for event-driven processing of objects, when [accept-event actions](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-actions.html#accept-event-action) are combined with object flows and "pins".

Other [behavioral UML diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html#behavior-diagram) come to mind as well for representing processes. You may consider for example:

- [*sequence diagram*](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html).  But these are more appropriate to represent **interaction scenarios between classes**.  They are less precise about complex synchronisation and less expressive for mixing control flow and object flows.
- [*state (machine) diagram*](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html).  These provide for forks and joins.  But it's a different viewpoint.  They are  more appropriate for describing the dynamic of **change of system or a component state** rather than a process.